# Select Element in Checkout not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm running a WooCommerce site for a client and I've got an issue where the select element which controls country and state selection during the checkout process does not work on an iPhone (5 or 6). Tapping the select field does not bring up your selection options.  The select fields do work on an iPad and also work on desktops/laptops.

Using Wordpress and de-activating all plugins and using the default theme I've determined there is something in my theme's code which is causing this issue.  The problem is that I don't know how to track it down.

You can access the site and test it at [www.viraone.com](http://www.viraone.com/product/chocolate-chaga-smoothie-mix/) drop the product into your cart and continuing to the checkout page you'll see you can't select the state/country select elements (on an iPhone).

The Code for the WooCommerce checkout is pretty standard but is found here.. https://gist.github.com/AndrewSepic/3fbd9c32f19faea0bce9c3d9bfd6e7aa

I've gone through the CSS and I haven't been able to find any obvious culprits and I'm not aware of how I can track which scripts from my theme are acting upon the select element. Any help with that area of developer tools would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post effort and code here in a [mcve]

Comment: **This is a theme issue…** The best way to handle this is to contact the author's theme support threads, opening a ticket there…

Comment: Hi @mplungjan I've been posting on SO and answering what questions I can to help others for a few years. Thanks for the welcome though.  i'm sorry I couldn't figure out how to post an MCVE because the WooCommerce checkout form is far from minimal code. It's so loaded that I felt it would actually just complicate the issue, but  I'll update with the code example momentarily.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec Yes, As I stated in the thread, I'm aware it's a theme issue.  I build my own themes using a theme frameworks and for this theme I used something called Reverie (a foundation 5 theme for WP) - http://themefortress.com/reverie/ It hasn't been updated by the developer since 2013 and I doubt I'll get any support from him.  If you haven any suggestions as to what may cause this issue, within a theme, I'd be happy to look into it.